# Why can't I edit posts from mobile?

Tags: bug, android-app

I am using the Android Stack Overflow's app to quickly access my account and eventually moderate/edit questions/answers. The problem I am having is I am unable to edit any answer even if I'm connected to my account:

> You don't have permission to edit this post

I am wondering if this is intended, in order to prevent people editing from their phone, maybe only those under a certain reputation or if it is only a bug?

UPDATE: image description below (app version: 1.0.4)

### [image]

[image]

Comment: Never seen that... are you sure you aren't edit blocked or something? If you try from the site, can you do it?

Comment: Is this new for you? Meaning, were you previously able to edit through the app and now can't, or is this your first time attempting?

Comment: Yes, for a given post I am able to edit it from the website but not from the app. But it's not new to me, I've already noticed that since I installed the app and never been able to edit from mobile

Comment: I think you can't suggest edits through the app.

Comment: You're right that's only suggested edits, not actual edits, but why ?

Comment: @gogaz likely the Android app is missing the ability to add to the review queue. For non-suggested edits, the update can be applied immediately.

Comment: Works fine for me, I edit questions all the time via the mobile app. I guess my edits aren't going through the review queue, though

Comment: Have you tried the stack exchange app? The stack overflow app is no longer developed and it appears to have been pulled from both the ios and andriod app stores https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-app-for-android