# What happened to the Stack Overflow app for Android?

Tags: discussion, support, android-app, stack-overflow-app, stack-overflow-history

The Stack Overflow app for Android doesn't exist anymore. [Google does still index it](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.stackoverflow&hl=en), but the page returns a 404.

The [iOS](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-overflow/id1155618808?mt=8) version seems to still exist, so not sure what happened there.

What's the reason for the removal of the app? What happened to it?

The reason why I'm interested in this is that the official Stack Exchange app for Android hasn't been updated for >1 year, and I wanted to (again) try out the Stack Overflow app to see if it became better since last year.

---

Seems like the iOS link is also dead now, as of at least April 2019.

Comment: _"Stack Exchange app for Android hasn't been updated for >1 year"_ This also means it has no "new contributor" banners. Just a completely random thought. :)

Comment: @E_net4 Damn, then we need to be nice to all users.

Comment: "to see if it became better since last year" it didn't. #savedyouaclick

Comment: FWIW, the mobile development on SE has been frozen since... [last year](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/241919)

Comment: The [Stack Exchange mobile app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin) still exist, they removed only the newer version, dedicated to Stack Overflow. You can still use the SE version, it has all sites. It's bad but might be better than nothing at all.

Comment: @ShadowWizard I found that app wayyy better than the SO app last year :)

Comment: @Rakete1111 dunno, never installed the SO app and think it was a huge mistake and waste of resources and time. But it's all buried in the past now. :) (The score of [the annoucement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/349255/stack-overflow-now-has-its-own-app-on-ios-and-android) confirms how bad it is.)

Comment: Why not just creating a 100 KB Android app containing just a `WebView` and displaying mobile `stackoverflow.com` website? Better than no app at all on Play Store, and costs 0 time and (nearly) 0$ in dev. Also no maintenance/updates needed when SO website has updates.

Comment: @ShadowWizard It seems that they focus on creating a usable Web Solution now, which makes way more sense to me than maintaining three distinct platforms. As Basj already pointed out, an Android app for the mobile view would be very easy to create

Comment: Holy crap the downvotes on the [app anouncement post](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/349255/2288578) are real!

Comment: @Clonkex sure they are, it was a horrible move in all aspects.

Comment: Is there any legit alternative so far?

Comment: I feel like Google has made it harder to harvest SO articles through Google Search as well. Worries me.

Comment: 29 Dec 2022, the stackoverflow app that I found on Android has tried to look like the one you see in the browser, but it is much less beautiful and harder to use, so  I uninstalled it

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Turns out that [Google has removed the Stack Overflow app from Google Play and Stack Exchange doesn't know why](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323330/about-section-has-old-copyright-date/323387?noredirect=1#comment1057276_323387).

Stack Exchange chose to not dig into it, since as the other answer already says, the app is no longer developed anyway, so it's pointless.

Comment: So why doesn't official open API for community to do that.

Comment: @Alex do what exactly?

Comment: I mean the mobile app. If Stack Exchange open their API, I think lots people would like to develop 3rd party app for SO. BTW, why there is no a PWA version for substitution at least.

Comment: @Alex the API is open, and even got a whole site dedicated to it and apps using it: https://stackapps.com/

Comment: cool, it's hard to find.

Comment: *Why* aren't the apps developed? What's the reason?

Comment: @NanashiNoGombe bit complicated, TL;DR is "money", you'll find the long version in [this answer by Kasra](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/296068/152859), who was the mobile team leader, and left SE long ago.

Comment: At least they should remove their suggestion from Profile -> Edit profile -> Applications

Comment: @netizen it's not a suggestion, it's used to give the app permission to access your data, I think. Anyway, [such request already been raised on MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/355910/the-applications-in-settings-page-is-still-showing-se-application-for-android).

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou it appears when you have no apps given the permission

Comment: @netizen sorry, now I don't understand what you mean. It appears in "Profile -> Edit profile -> Applications" only after you use the app for the first time. It doesn't exist before that. If you don't use the app anymore you can safely remove it.

Comment: @ShadowWizardisEarForYou I went to that section where I had the two legacy apps, so I removed them, and reloaded the page. Now instead of a listing I see three boxes titled **You have no authorized applications, here are some suggestions** where the android one tells me to install SE Remote app, leading to a Google's Play Store error URL

Comment: @netizen ohhh. Sorry, had no idea that's what you meant. Feel free to start a feature request on Meta Stack Exchange to remove those suggestions, you're totally right as the apps are dead and similar suggestions have been [removed recently from emails](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/354758/remove-stack-exchange-mobile-app-download-buttons-from-emails).

Answer (score 52):

The development on the mobile apps have been [abandoned](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/245360) for more than a year.

You can use the still existing [Stack Exchange app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin), which include all sites on the network, including Stack Overflow.

I would advise you to try to set the mobile web site in responsive mode (by default it still switches to the mobile site, so you might need to switch to the *Desktop site*). It works better than the app, and you have many more features available to you.

Comment: The question seems to be about the SE app. Do you know whether "the apps" in the linked answer refers to both the SE and SO app?

Comment: I think they developed the SO app from scratch; it doesn't seem like a stripped version of the SE app though.

Comment: The mobile team has different tasks now. Whether they derived the SO app from the SE app or not isn't relevant in this case.

Comment: Hmm, @Patrick, is there still a mobile team? AFAIK, Kasra left on 18th June this year. Brian Nickel is working on the new user indicator, the comment dialog and other website fixes.

Comment: So Brian has a different ask as said. I indeed heard that Kasra left on personal reasons. @BhargavRao

Comment: Ah! I thought that by different tasks, you meant different mobile app related tasks and I got confused. Can no longer call them mobile team. ;)

Comment: Well, then the development wasn't really abandoned, right? ;) @BhargavRao

Comment: Heh, true. Which is why you shouldn't meta with sleepy eyes.

Comment: @Bhargav There isn't any mobile team afaik. I think The DAG team is working, among other things, on the new responsive design which will replace the mobile web at some point.

Comment: OMG, not the responsive mode. Just tested it and it is still the same https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/369381/the-new-design-is-completely-unusable-on-mobile-in-desktop-mode/369389#369389

Comment: Is the responsive mode a PWA? If not, it should be.

Comment: Isn't it enough it actually works? ;) @jhpratt

Comment: PWAs aren't _terribly_ difficult to create if you already have a functional webapp.

Comment: After seeing all these comments, is it legal for a developer to develop custom version of native Android App using Stackoverflow's API?

Comment: I guess Patrick means "yes, you can create a native Android app using SE API (e.g. [there are Android apps on Stack Apps](https://stackapps.com/questions/tagged/android), but don't impersonate as from Stack Exchange/Stack Overflow" (of course, restricted to the limitation of public SE API, since some functions in official apps are using private SE API)

Comment: @AndrewT. That, yes. You can.

Comment: Stackexchange app is currently also not available on playstore

Comment: ... and it now looks like the StackExchange app may also never be resurrected - see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353133#356369