# Android app: comments are offset when they have votes

Tags: bug, design, android-app

I noticed while reading my newsletter in bed this morning that comments that receive votes are offset to the right slightly compared to comments that don't have votes. It looks like the vote count is pushing the comment to the right. This is inconsistent with the full desktop experience.

[image: pls fix]

Compare this to the same comment thread on full SO where all the comments are aligned equally:

[image: comment thread on full SO]

The mobile web version of SO does not show this behaviour either:
[image: comment thread on mobile web SO]

Comment: At this point, I'm afraid that the app will never be updated since [it has gone from the Play Store listing](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/373307/what-happened-to-the-stack-overflow-app-for-android)...