# SE for Android links to blog.SE.com

Tags: bug, android-app, broken-link

If I go to "Edit Profile & Settings > Applications", the official app of SE shows up. However, when I click on it, it links to https://blog.stackexchange.com, the homepage of the blog.

Note that this is not the removed SO app, this is the SE app.
[image: Broken link]

Comment: I think this belongs to [meta.se](https://meta.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @IvankaTodorova bugs and FR can be posted on any meta.

Comment: Considering that [this isn't really a thing anymore](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/379742/1079354), having the link *not* be broken as opposed to point to something a user can never use again is preferable.

Comment: @Makoto as I wrote in the question, this is not the SO app, this is the SE app, which still exists.

Comment: [I'm not convinced](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/300389/175248).  There hasn't been any motion on the mobile apps - *either* of them - in ***quite*** a long time (Play Store says June '17).

Comment: @Makoto Just because an application (mobile or otherwise) is not actively maintained, doesn't mean that it is not useful or not being used. I use plenty of applications that haven't been maintained for years, but their functionality is still intact and useful. Also, the [iOS version of the SE App links to stackexchange.com](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59jKG.png).

Comment: @Makoto Google only removed the SO app, not the SE app